# Inno Setup installator has wrong text encoding

Tags: windows, character-encoding, inno-setup

My installator (Inno Setup) has a bad Russian text encoding for the some Windows installations. All machines have Windows XP SP3 (English version), but on some this works, some does not have.

There are any settings on Windows to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the Non-Unicode version of Inno Setup. The machines, where the installer has wrong encoding, probably do not have the Russian set as the legacy (non-Unicode) encoding.

In Windows XP Control panel, check the *"Regional and Language Options"*. There on the *Advanced* tab check, what is the *"Language for non-Unicode programs"* set to. This can be a different language than the Windows UI language. If I'm correct, the working machines have this set to *Russian* and the non-working machines have this set to *English* (or other).

---

Anyway, always use the [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode) and you won't have this kind of problems.

No one should be developing non-Unicode applications in the 21st century!

Comment: Thanks, this is my bad habit - installing software version, where downloads count is more, and not reading documentation:)